# Programmatically launch user selected application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, launcher

So, if you haven't noticed. Many new launchers give you the option to select an application to be launched as default for a specific category.

My launcher consists of different fragments which displays cards, these cards hold a button which has a function where when the user touches the button, they're prompted with a window where they can select which application to run for that specific view. To make things easier for the user, the intent or app they selected should be saved, so if they select the button again, they don't have to select the app again.

If you would like a few examples to what I mean, take a look at 9 Cards Launcher or Smart Launcher, or any Windows 7 Phone Launcher. They prompt you with a small pop up which lets you select the application you want to run and its set.

how can I achieve this? Please I have literally searched everywhere, but nothings making sense. There are no tutorials on this, I have also decompiled various launchers to see how this works but I don't know where to start.

It'd be great if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

> **1st of all you need to get the Installed Applications.**
>
> **Then you will get the application package info from the user selected Application.**
>
> **Finally launch the intent.**

Here's what you can try out:

1. Create an intent with `action=MAIN` and `category=LAUNCHER`
2. Get the [**PackageManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) from the current context using `context.getPackageManager`
3. `packageManager.queryIntentActivity(&lt;intent&gt;, 0)` where intent has `category=LAUNCHER`, `action=MAIN` or `packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0)` to get the first activity with main/launcher
4. Get the [**ActivityInfo**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html) you're interested in
5. From the `ActivityInfo`, get the `packageName` and `name`
6. Finally, create another intent with with `category=LAUNCHER`, `action=MAIN`, `componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name)` and `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`
7. Finally, `context.startActivity(newIntent)`

> **I would also suggest to take a look at [FreeTaskManager](https://code.google.com/p/freetaskmanager/)**